# How do I transfer my parsed array data from one class to another?

Tags: java, xml, picocli

My program uses Picocli to parse XML data and store it in an ArrayList. For some reason, the information gets removed when I try to access it from another class.

I run the code below, and it shows the elements just fine:

```java
public class SourceSentences {
    static String source;
    static ArrayList<String> sourceArray = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void translate() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        String xmlFileLocation = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\exercise\\source.txml";
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println("Get Text From Source File: ");
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        builderFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

        //parse '.txml' file
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File(xmlFileLocation));
        //...
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //specify tag in the '.txml' file and iterate
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("segment");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            //this is tag index of where line of el are
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            //check if actually a node
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //create a node object that will retrieve the element in the XML file
                Element element = (Element) node;
                //get the element from the specified node in nodeList
                source = element.getElementsByTagName("source").item(0).getTextContent();
                //check what it looks like
                System.out.println(source);
                //add to arraylist
                sourceArray.add(source);
            }

            /*String[] arr = source.split("\\s");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));*/
        }

        //get its data type to make sure
        System.out.println("data type: " + source.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(sourceArray);
    }
}
```

So I try to access sourceArray from another class:

```java
class getArrayElements extends SourceSentences{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SourceSentences.sourceArray);
    }
}
```

and results in variables being [], thus not able to transfer data to another class.

Picocli setup snippet:

```java
public class TranslateTXML implements Callable<String> {

    @Option(names = "-f", description = " path to source txml file")

    private String file;

    @Option(names = "-o", description = "output path")
    private String output;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = new picocli.CommandLine(new TranslateTXML()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.equals("C:\\Users\\gnier\\Desktop\\exercise\\source.txml")) {
                sourceSent("C:\\Users\\gnier\\Desktop\\exercise\\source.txml");
                System.out.println("source.txml data retrieved\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File \"source.txml\" not found. Check FileName and Directory.");
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }

        WriteSourceTranslatedToTXML.makeTranslated(System.out);
        System.out.println("translated made");
        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println("File \"translated.txml\" has been outputted to designated path");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` context of the `SourceSentences.main()` is lost once you run the `getArrayElements.main()` method. The parsing of your XML data never happened as far as `getArrayElements.main()` was concerned.

You need to call the `translate` method from inside the `getArrayElements`' *main* function.

```java
class getArrayElements extends SourceSentences {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        SourceSentences.translate();
        System.out.println(SourceSentences.sourceArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! But when I try to access the array elements in sourceArray from a method in getArrayElements, it still results in []. How can I do that? Or maybe there's something in what you're saying that I'm not understanding. Sorry!!!

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is to be able to extract sentences from a source.xml that's in my computer, store them, and then place them in a new xml file under <tag>sourceArray.get(0)</tag> that I wrote. 
But since I can't get the sourceArray elements, I can't place them in the new xml file. Does that make sense?

Maybe throw the entire creating xml code into the main method?

Comment: @Barath Kumar I tried your recommendation, but it didn't work. The array elements were still not transferred. I am getting the elements originally from a nodeList and then putting them in an arrayList. Could that be why?

Comment: Hey @EmekaA, are you trying to again access the sourceArray from different context? Basically, you need to do all the processing, accessing the array and again writing it to different xml from a single main method. Each main method will have its own run time environment and whatever operation you do on data structures is not persisted outside of this context, unless its a file that you are writing to (which gets saved to the hard disk).

Comment: Oops. I did not mean to add those main methods in the other classes. Okay, so I need to call everything from the main() that's in the command line setup class. So within one cmd option I could build the xml file and then the other option, just do a file I/O and finish adding whatever else after getting the data from the api, and anything else?

Comment: so I could do something like:  $java MyApp -f [get file from disk and extract sentences] -x [build new xml file] -y [make api call and get api data]  -o [open built xml file and input all data]